# Suggestions of using TensorFlow for action prediction

Tags: tensorflow, unity-game-engine, neural-network

I am currently developing a RTS game and using TensorFlow for it's AI.

We are using the world state (numerical values that represent current resources, units and buildings) as the input values and the output values as the desired world state. We have the same amount of inputs as outputs. Each output value represents the new value of the input stats (eg. more gold, more peasants, less wood, etc).

Here is the current model we are implementing in tensorflow:

```
neuralnet = Sequential()
neuralnet.add(Dense(output_dim = 13, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 13)) 
neuralnet.add(Dense(output_dim = 13, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu')) 
neuralnet.add(Dense(output_dim = 13, init = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0);
neuralnet.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = ['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
```

We are training this network using recorded world states saved as snapshots from real players. We are using these snapshots as inputs, and their next snapshot as ouputs (eg. if the input is the snapshot n, its output would be the snapshot n+1). For testing we are using this code to simulate a match:

```
simulation_outputs = []

for i in range(1,100):
    output_pred = neuralnet.predict(initial_state)
    initial_state = output_pred
    denorm_output = sc.inverse_transform(output_pred)
    simulation_outputs.append(denorm_output)
```

We expect the output numbers to be (almost) always incremental, but after a few of these outputs are reached, the numbers start stagnating until they come to a full stop. Is there a reason for this? Or is it expected behaviour?

We need to know which should be the best way to model the network to accomplish this task and prevent the match progression to stagnate like this.

Any kind of help would be welcomed

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an implementation problem so it might be more appropriate to ask at [stats.stackexchange.com]. Anyway, I would suggest making the output be a probability distribution of likely states, instead of exactly one state. This might help avoid your rollouts having infinite loops.

Comment: I'd expect the numbers to stagnate at/below 1 because of the sigmoid activation function in the last layer. Is that the behaviour you're experiencing?